# IfElse and use of variables?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I need to loop trough 20 rows and add an equation to a worksheet that differs by variables. I'm using a If.... Else If statement, and I think I need to declare variable as I am only populating the second row of data.

My Code:

```
Do While counter < 20
        counter = counter + 1
    If CNum = 269 And SCode = 7168 Then
        NTotal = ("=(C2*35)/1000")
        Range("E2").Value = NTotal
    ElseIf CNum = 269 And SCode = 7181 Then
        NTotal = ("=(C2*2.5)/1000")
        Range("E2").Value = NTotal
    ElseIf CNum = 269 And SCode = 7183 Then
        NTotal = ("=(2*(D2-C2))/1000+50")
        Range("E2").Value = NTotal
    End If
Loop
```

Do I simply declare a range value for C2, D2, and E2 to make this work?

Joe

Comment: why don't you do this with a simple formula in your worksheet? (I'm just curious... if you don't need to do it in VBA and there's a simpler way, I think you can explore it)

Comment: It's part of a larger re-format that I'm doing on a worksheet that is a repetitive task. Looking to simplify the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working but two things:

Firstly because CNum and scode aren't changing within the loop they always have the same value so only the first matching condition will ever be met for each iteration

Secondly, if you want to increment rows then you need to include 'counter' to increment the rows element of your 'range' statements.  An example could be as follows:

```
Do While counter < 20
        counter = counter + 1
    If CNum = 269 And scode = 7168 Then
        NTotal = ("=(C2*35)/1000")
        Cells(counter + 1, 5).Value = NTotal
    ElseIf CNum = 269 And scode = 7181 Then
        NTotal = ("=(C2*2.5)/1000")
        Cells(counter + 1, 5).Value = NTotal
    ElseIf CNum = 269 And scode = 7183 Then
        NTotal = ("=(2*(D2-C2))/1000+50")
        Cells(counter + 1, 5).Value = NTotal
    End If
Loop
```

**Edit**

You may also care to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687800/why-use-range-formula-in-vba-vbe-for-excel-2003-instead-of-range-value)

Comment: I'm confused. If I am looking at two values, how is it that they aren't changing within the loop? The Scode changes, the CNum stays the same.

Comment: Your If ElseIf statements CHECK on the value of the variables, they don't actually change them.  So if 'scode' is set at 5000 going into this loop, it is still 5000 when the loop exits.  Did you run the code and did it work OK for you?

Comment: I did run the code but I get the first formula for each row independent of the Scode.

Comment: You should only get one formula in col E, in each of the 20 rows depending on which condition is met.  If no conditions are met then the cell in that particular row  won't change.  Try stepping through your code line by line and observe what goes on.  To do this set a breakpoint on the first line of the loop code, run the code and when it breaks at your breakpoint, step through one line at a time using F8 key.

Comment: That's what I thought it would do, but when I step through it, it only finds the first condition, 20 times, and then ends.

Comment: Yep its working correctly - as I said earlier nothing is happening inside the loop to change any conditions

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why it's not stepping down through each row, but I guess it's back to google to find an answer. Thanks for your help thus far.