# VBA to create formula causes 1004 error when parentheses entered and causes an update values box when space is entered

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a UserForm with TextBoxes that are used in creating new sheets from a template.

The gist of how this all works is that the VBA creates a copy of a "template sheet" that is hidden in the workbook.  It names this copy based on the values entered by the user in the form's TextBox.

Additionally, I have a Summary sheet that is, as the name implies, a summary of different information entered in the sheet(s) the user has created.

To relieve the need for users to manually copy info into the Summary sheet, I'm using a formula tied to a function which will update the Summary sheet for them.

Now, when the user finishes entering their information into the UserForm, they click a Generate Workbook button which runs the code below which build formulas into the Summary sheet based on the info entered in the UserForm TextBox.

**I have two issues when the VBA attempts to add a formula to the cells in the Summary Sheet.**

**Issue 1:**
When a space is entered into the TextBox, it opens a "Update Values" dialog box when the user clicks the Generate Workbook button.
Example - Project 1234

**Issue 2:**
When parentheses are entered into the TextBox, a 1004 error occurs when the user clicks the Generate Workbook button.
Example - Project1234(Mobile)

If no parentheses and no spaces are entered, it all works fine.

There are 25 possible entries in the UserForm.
Each entry has three TextBoxes: ProjectNameTXT, SheetNameTXT, and ProjectNumTXT - each numbered 1-25 (i.e., ProjectNameTXT1, SheetNameTXT1, ProjectNumTXT1).
The two issues **only** pertain to the SheetNameTXT TextBoxes.

The csvRange is the function I mentioned earlier.

Here's the relevant code.

**Code in UserForm1:**

```
Private Sub GenerateWorkbook_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim k As Long
    Dim strSName

    For k = 1 To 25

        strSName = Me.Controls("SheetNameTXT" & k).Text

            'Creates a data sheet for each project.
            'Uses the MASTER SHEET as a template.
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER SHEET")
            ws.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = strSName
            ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Select

           'THIS IS THE CODE CAUSING THE ISSUES
            Range("B" & k + 3).Value = "=IF(ISERROR(csvRange(" & strSName & "!A2:A2500)),"""",csvRange(" & strSName & "!A2:A2500))"

    Next k

    Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

**Code for the Function csvRange:**

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    For Each entry In myRange
        If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then

            'Create comma separated value
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ", "

        End If
    Next

    'Removes the last comma and space.
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 2)

End Function
```

The csvRange function is a modified version of this function that muncherelli created:
https://superuser.com/a/241233

I'm not the world's greatest VBA coder, so apologies if my syntax or methodology sucks.  Feel free to improve and provide suggestions if you are so inclined.

I searched StackOverflow and didn't find anything that would solve the problem.  Tried some of the solutions suggested for similar problems but no luck getting them to fix these issues.

As always, your help and constructive criticism are much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure about using a function in a formula but to assign the formula to a cell use Range().Formula   Range("B" & k + 3).Formula= "=IF(ISERROR(csvRange(" & strSName & "!A2:A2500)),"""",csvRange(" & strSName & "!A2:A2500))"

Comment: Thanks MatthewD.  Question: is there a particular reason for using Formula instead of Value?  Just better syntax or something like that?  Doesn't seem to have an affect on my two issues.

Comment: Here is a bit of info.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687800/why-use-range-formula-in-vba-vbe-for-excel-2003-instead-of-range-value

Comment: Try putting single quotes around your sheet name in your formula. "=IF(ISERROR(csvRange('" & strSName & "'!A2:A2500)),"""",csvRange('" & strSName & "'!A2:A2500))

Comment: Well, amazingly that worked.  Looks like it fixed both issues.  Earlier, I saw a solution that had single quotes, but I put them completely in the wrong places so it didn't work.  Thank very much MatthewD.  Been staring at this stupid formula for way too long.  Thanks for providing a second set of eyes and the great info.  Feel free to add that as an answer so I can give you the credit / the check for the answer.

Comment: If you use Named Range you can get rid of Sheet name and `!A2:A2500`. Alternatively for the csvRange, you can add the ", " in front then at the end use `Mid(3,csvRangeOutput)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put single quotes around your sheet name in your formula.

```
"=IF(ISERROR(csvRange('" & strSName & "'!A2:A2500)),"""",csvRange('" & strSName & "'!A2:A2500))
```