# VBA variable string concatenation

Tags: vba, excel

I have a variable a = "C2"
and variable b = "C3"

I need to do something like

```
ws.Range("A2").Value = "=" & a &"" ""& b
```

which should return:

```
=C2&" "&C3
```

in an excel formula however I cant seem to get this to work anyone have a solution??

Comment: Are you trying to get your cell to have the formula `=C2&" "&C3`, or do you want it to show the values of C2 and C3, separated by a space?  Try `ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=" & a & "&"" ""&" & b`.  If you want the *values* of your variables, separated by a space, use `ws.Range("A2").Value = a & " " & b`.

Comment: @BruceWayne this is the correct answer the first one worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment,

`ws.Range("A2").Formula = "=" & a & "&"" ""&" & b`

This works because you need to use [`.Formula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) instead of `.Value`.

Comment: Actually also works with .Value interestingly enough

Comment: @TylerCowan - UUhmmm, I'm just going to ignore that then, to keep my sanity :P I *thought* I was getting the hang of VBA, and then you tell me I can do `.Value` just the same.  If someone can comment as to why, that'd be appreciated! Perhaps it's because you're using an `=` at the start, so of course, when Excel sees an `=` at the start, it uses it as a formula.  I wonder then, what the "real" big difference in using `.Value` and `.Formula` for setting formulas is.

Comment: Imagine you have integers, doubles for certain calculations and if you use .formula you gonna get screwed. Because .FORMULA always return a String. (Any value set to .formula without is a plain value not a formula) Unless you have exception handling and the extras ready in your code. Whereas .VALUE returns your data's data type as you expect them to be.

In terms of retrieving formula: Value is one way road in case to set formula but not to retrieve.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687800/why-use-range-formula-in-vba-for-excel-2003-instead-of-range-value