# Dynamic reference cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make this formula dynamic in VBA?

Range("A" & alastrow + 2).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Data'!$D$9:$D$1642,MATCH(0,IF(B18='Data'!$G$9:$G$1642,COUNTIF(A17,'Data'!$D$9:$D$1642), """"), 0)), """")"

I would like B18 and A17 to change depending on where my data starts on the sheet, but I am unsure how to do that. I am not sure if it matters, but the range referenced before the start of the array is A18. Does anyone know how I could accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Use helper column(s) and indirect to reference these markers/tags you create. Alternative you can with  indirect & cell(row)  and or cell (address) to reference .

Comment: I'd guess just as you use `alastrow ` in `Range("A" & alastrow + 2)`

Comment: Doh thought it was just excel . Yes I'd go with Storax exactly.

Comment: So I can do something like Range("A" & alastrow + 2).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Data'!$D$9:$D$1642,MATCH(0,IF(alastrow='Data'!$G$9:$G$1642,COUNTIF(A17,'Data'!$D$9:$D$1642), """"), 0)), """")" where I replaced the B18 with alastrow. Sorry, I am new to this.

Comment: Not like that, you have to use quotation marks to separate the string  and the variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777486/vba-variable-string-concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some colleagues tried to explain in the comments, you have to use the `&` operator to concatenate (join) the static parts of your formula with the variable `alastrow`. Take a look:

```
Range("A" & alastrow + 2).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Data'!$D$9:$D$1642,MATCH(0,IF(" & alastrow & "='Data'!$G$9:$G$1642,COUNTIF(" & alastrow & ",'Data'!$D$9:$D$1642), """"), 0)), """")"
```